# updatedselectizeinput with dplyr in shinyApp

Tags: r, shiny

I am not able to give reference of column name from dbgetquery to the option choices specifying the column name from the query in updateselectizeinput in shiny. Can anyone help?

Example code:

```
query= reactive({ con, 'select * from database' }) 
updateselectizeinput(session, 'inputid', choice="how to give reference from query here", server=TRUE)
```

Comment: It is very hard to understand what is Your problem, please provide reproducible example and format Your question.

Comment: I have a dbgetquery which contains the column name. while using updateselectizeinput we are supposed to give the choice specifying the variable name. I am not getting how to give the refernece of column name. e.g query= reactive({ con, 'select * from database' })   updateselecteizeinput(session, 'inputid', choice="how to give reference from query here", server=TRUE)

Comment: Do You wanna specify column name in `dbgetQuery`? Is Your Query reactive (You choose different columns)? Still not really clear. Why do You need `updateselectizeInput` if You do not have `selectizeInput`?

Comment: query3= reactive({
   
   dbGetQuery(con$cc,"select VAR   FROM datatable")
   
  })   observe({ 
   updateSelectizeInput(session, "sel4",choices=unique(rownames(query3())), server=TRUE)
   
 })  THIS is giving me error! p.s.- I want to give reference of column name from dbgetquery to choices!

Comment: Why do You need `updateselectizeInput` if You do not have `selectizeInput`?

Comment: I do have selectizeinput and that is working fine. selectizeInput("sel4","type variable", choices="NULL", options= list(placeholder= "TYPE VAR ", maxOPTIONS=1100)

Comment: The problem is coming in the updateselectizeinput only, please suggest me how to get rid of it!

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is very hard to understand what exactly do You mean, but i will just assume that You want to use the column names from the database table as a choice in `selectizeInput`. For this purpose You do not need `updateSelectizeInput`.

Here is the sample code with additional comments in it:

```
library(shiny)
u <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Mutually Dependent Input"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("select1")),
    mainPanel()
  )
)) 
s <- shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {

  queryOutput <-  reactive({ 
    data <-  dbGetQuery(con, 'select * from database')}) # Here is Your SQL Query which gives You the table

  output$select1 <- renderUI({
    selectizeInput("select1_ui", "Select column name", choices = names(queryOutput())) # Here is Your selectizeInput with choices as column names
  })

})
shinyApp(u,s)
```

Comment: No, basically I want to use selectizeinput to display different categories of a variable. So, in the server, when I am trying to use updateselectizeinput, I am not able to give reference of the column name(from dbgetquery) whose choices is to be displayed. Such that if a user selects a category, results corresponding to that is displayed. I hope it is clear now?)